# Newsletter Block?

Tags: newsletter

there suppose to be a default Newsletter Block on my template, however I cannot see it.
How do I add a 'Sign up for Newsletter' box on my homepage?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a newsletter block on the default theme app/design/frontend/rwd/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml which is usually placed in the footer or elsewhere in the newsletter.xml layout file.

Comment: Yes so I was told, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

please to `admin >Select your cms pageDesign > Custom design > Custom Layout Update XM`L field plwase put the code

```
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.newsletter"
 as="home.newsletter" before="footer_store_language" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
```

Comment: This is also described on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420285/newsletter-signup-on-cms-page-in-magento -- using CMS directives instead.

Comment: Is it custom practice to store xml layout changes in the database rather than in the layout .xml files? I would have thought the oposite tbh.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that didn't work, I also tried adding {{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}} to a block and no joy either.

I think Im missing a step or two, can anyone guide me a bit more please?